Add hyperlink with onClick function using jsPDF
im trying to create a hyperlink in a generated pdf file, that when the user clicks on it, it will generate and donwload a new pdf.
what i have is :
    if (codition) {

    pdf.setFontSize(16);
    pdf.setTextColor(0, 0, 255); 

    pdf.textWithLink('Download Full Content', x , y , {
      url: 'javascript:void(0)',
      onClick: () => generatePDF(index)
    });
  }



 const generatePDF= async index => {
      const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
      const content = this.widgets[index].innerHTML;

      pdf.text(content, 20, 20);

      pdf.save('Content.pdf');
    };

however when i click on the link nothing is been downloaded. can someone spot what am i missing?
